# clear interval on hover

Tags: jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

have a custom made slider which I would like to stop on hover. I've tried to clear and set the interval on hover but doesn't work properly. It stops only the first time I hover on it then if I move the mouse out and in again it doesn't stop.

here's my code:

```
    var itvl = null;

    itvl = window.setInterval(function(){scroll_()},3000);

    function scroll_() {
        if ($('#carousel_ul li').length > 1) {
            $("#right_scroll").click();
        }
    }

    $('#carousel_ul li').hover(function() {
        window.clearInterval(itvl);    
    }, function() {
        window.setInterval(function(){scroll_()},3000);
    });
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Mauro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are setting the interval on the hover-off, you are not setting itvl.  itvl is actually an integer that acts as a reference to the interval.  So the reference changes when you do `window.setInterval(function(){scroll_()},3000);` without reffing it to anything.

Try this instead:

```
$('#carousel_ul li').hover(function() {
    window.clearInterval(itvl);    
}, function() {
    itvl = window.setInterval(function(){scroll_()},3000);
});
```

Comment: Great!  Glad I could help.  Remember to mark as answered if it resolved your issue.  (I think you have to wait 15 mins after you ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#carousel_ul li').hover(function() {
    window.clearInterval(itvl);    
}, function() {
    itvl = window.setInterval(function(){scroll_()},3000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean variable rather than clearInterval:

```
    var scrolling= true;    
    window.setInterval(scroll_,3000);    
    function scroll_() {
        if(scrolling) {
            if ($('#carousel_ul li').length > 1) {
               $("#right_scroll").click();
            }
        }
    }    
    $('#carousel_ul li').hover(function() {
        scrolling = false;    
    }, function() {
        scrolling = true;
    });
```